# PRISM resolve interface with factory that uses type to resolve

Tags: c#, prism

I have been building a application with PRISM, this application is going to be groing alot over the coming years so it is set up modular and with IoC in mind.
In this application I am currently implementing Nlog for the logging mechanism.

Because I do not want to add a reference to NLog throughout my whole application I have created an interface for the logger

```
public interface ILog
{
    void Log(LogLevel loglevel, string format);
    void Log(LogLevel loglevel, string format, params object[] args);
    void Log(LogLevel loglevel, Exception exc, string format, params object[] args);
}
```

I have also created an interface for the factory

```
public interface ILogFactory
{
    ILog Initialize(Type type);
}
```

The factory takes a Type parameter that can be used to created a logger specific for that class. Now comes the challenge where I am going to use the ILog I would like to have a instance using the target types class.

```
public class ClassA
{
    private ILog Logger { get; set;}
    public ClassA(Ilog logger)
    {
        Logger = logger;
    }
}
```

How can I wire my ILogFactory into PRISM so on a resolve of a class that uses Ilog that is uses the ILogFactory.Initialize(Type type) with in this case typeof(ClassA).

Comment: you could simply inject the ILogFactory as a dependency into ClassA. Class a is just using the instance of the factory which happens to be a ILog implementation.

Comment: I am currently using that and it works, but just have to have an Ilog makes the class simpler

Comment: Yes I understand what you want to achieve, but it does not work that way.
Your class depends on the Factory sicne it does not know how to create an ILogger, but the Factory does - so the Factory is a dependency for your class. I think you are just overthinking this issue. Just let the class depend on the factory and you are good to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after searching more of the web I finally found what I was looking for at
[this blog](http://blog.baltrinic.com/software-development/dotnet/log4net-integration-with-unity-ioc-container)

I had to modify the code a bid to make it not depend on log4net this resulted in the following code

A BuildTrackingExtension which we need to know where the logger we are going the create is needed.

```
public class BuildTrackingExtension : UnityContainerExtension
{
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Context.Strategies.AddNew<BuildTrackingStrategy>(UnityBuildStage.TypeMapping);
    }

    public static IBuildTrackingPolicy GetPolicy(IBuilderContext context)
    {
        return context.Policies.Get<IBuildTrackingPolicy>(context.BuildKey, true);
    }

    public static IBuildTrackingPolicy SetPolicy(IBuilderContext context)
    {
        IBuildTrackingPolicy policy = new BuildTrackingPolicy();
        context.Policies.SetDefault(policy);
        return policy;
    }
}

public class BuildTrackingStrategy : BuilderStrategy
{
    public override void PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
    {
        var policy = BuildTrackingExtension.GetPolicy(context)
            ?? BuildTrackingExtension.SetPolicy(context);

        policy.BuildKeys.Push(context.BuildKey);
    }

    public override void PostBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
    {
        IBuildTrackingPolicy policy = BuildTrackingExtension.GetPolicy(context);
        if ((policy != null) && (policy.BuildKeys.Count > 0))
        {
            policy.BuildKeys.Pop();
        }
    }
}

public interface IBuildTrackingPolicy : IBuilderPolicy
{
    Stack<object> BuildKeys { get; }
}

public class BuildTrackingPolicy : IBuildTrackingPolicy
{
    public BuildTrackingPolicy()
    {
        BuildKeys = new Stack<object>();
    }

    public Stack<object> BuildKeys { get; private set; }
}
```

Then a LogCreationExtension to create the logger from my ILogFactory

```
public class LogCreationExtension : UnityContainerExtension
{
    private ILogFactory LogFactory;
    private LogCreationStrategy strategy;

    public LogCreationExtension(ILogFactory logFactory)
    {
        LogFactory = logFactory;
    }
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        strategy = new LogCreationStrategy(LogFactory);

        Context.Strategies.Add(strategy, UnityBuildStage.PreCreation);
    }
}

public class LogCreationStrategy : BuilderStrategy
{
    public bool IsPolicySet { get; private set; }

    private ILogFactory LogFactory;
    public LogCreationStrategy(ILogFactory logFactory)
    {
        LogFactory = logFactory;
    }

    public override void PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
    {
        Type typeToBuild = context.BuildKey.Type;
        if (typeof(ILog).Equals(typeToBuild))
        {

            if (context.Policies.Get<IBuildPlanPolicy>(context.BuildKey) == null)
            {
                Type typeForLog = LogCreationStrategy.GetLogType(context);
                IBuildPlanPolicy policy = new LogBuildPlanPolicy(typeForLog, LogFactory);
                context.Policies.Set<IBuildPlanPolicy>(policy, context.BuildKey);

                IsPolicySet = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public override void PostBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
    {
        if (IsPolicySet)
        {
            context.Policies.Clear<IBuildPlanPolicy>(context.BuildKey);
            IsPolicySet = false;
        }
    }

    private static Type GetLogType(IBuilderContext context)
    {
        Type logType = null;
        IBuildTrackingPolicy buildTrackingPolicy = BuildTrackingExtension.GetPolicy(context);
        if ((buildTrackingPolicy != null) && (buildTrackingPolicy.BuildKeys.Count >= 2))
        {
            logType = ((NamedTypeBuildKey)buildTrackingPolicy.BuildKeys.ElementAt(1)).Type;
        }
        else
        {
            StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
            //first two are in the log creation strategy, can skip over them
            for (int i = 2; i < stackTrace.FrameCount; i++)
            {
                StackFrame frame = stackTrace.GetFrame(i);
                logType = frame.GetMethod().DeclaringType;
                if (!logType.FullName.StartsWith("Microsoft.Practices"))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return logType;
    }
}

public class LogBuildPlanPolicy : IBuildPlanPolicy
{
    private ILogFactory LogFactory;
    public LogBuildPlanPolicy(Type logType, ILogFactory logFactory)
    {
        LogType = logType;
        LogFactory = logFactory;
    }

    public Type LogType { get; private set; }

    public void BuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
    {
        if (context.Existing == null)
        {
            ILog log = LogFactory.Initialize(LogType);
            context.Existing = log;
        }
    }
}
```

Wiring it up using unity

```
        //Container.RegisterType<ILogFactory, NLogLogFactory>();
        Container.RegisterInstance<ILogFactory>(_LogFactory);
        Container.AddNewExtension<BuildTrackingExtension>();
        Container.AddNewExtension<LogCreationExtension>();
```

I am using RegisterInstance because I am using the logfactory before InitializeShell is called